# Recortar la diagonal de una matriz en python

Tags: python, matrices, numpy

tengo el siguiente problema:

Dada la siguiente matriz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como hago para que me quede así?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve tratando con np.diag pero no me resultó.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `np.tril(array, k)` hace exactamente lo que quieres, de hecho, es más general, consigue la matriz triangular inferior (por eso, el `tril`,  de triangular-lower) que esta debajo de la k-ésima diagonal.

#### Ejemplo:

```
array = np.array([[1,2,3],
                  [4,5,6],
                  [7,8,9]])
```

---

```
np.tril(array, -1)
```

> ```
>  array([[0, 0, 0],
>         [4, 0, 0],
>         [7, 8, 0]])
> ```

---

```
np.tril(array, 0)
```

> ```
>  array([[1, 0, 0],
>         [4, 5, 0],
>         [7, 8, 9]])
> ```

#### Documentación:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html

Comment: Funcionó excelente, muchas gracias.